# using Cakephp Restful WS with primary key different from default 'id'

Tags: web-services, cakephp, routes

I want to create a Webservice in cakephp but the primary key is not id_supp but taken the default value id

this is the modal:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Supplier extends AppModel {

    var $primaryKey = 'id_supp';
```

this is the route

```
Router::mapResources(array('suppliers'));
```

and this is the view action

```
public function view($id) {
        $supplier = $this->Supplier->findById($id);
        $this->set(array(
            'supplier' => $supplier,
            '_serialize' => array('supplier')
        ));
    }
```

The result when accessing the following url via GET

```
/suppliers/54f4dc83-0bd0-4fdd-ab8b-0a08ba3b5702.json
```

is:

```
{
"code": 500,
"url": "\/TN\/Back_rest\/suppliers\/54f4dc83-0bd0-4fdd-ab8b-0a08ba3b5702.json",
"name": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;Supplier.id&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039;",
"error": {
    "errorInfo": [
        "42S22",
        1054,
        "Unknown column 'Supplier.id' in 'where clause'"
    ],
    "queryString": "SELECT `Supplier`.`id_supp`, `Supplier`.`company_name`, `Supplier`.`contact_name`, `Supplier`.`contact_title`, `Supplier`.`address`, `Supplier`.`postcode`, `Supplier`.`phone`, `Supplier`.`fax`, `Supplier`.`www`, `Supplier`.`active`, `Supplier`.`created`, `Supplier`.`modified` FROM `tn`.`suppliers` AS `Supplier`   WHERE `Supplier`.`id` = '54f4dc83-0bd0-4fdd-ab8b-0a08ba3b5702'    LIMIT 1"
}}
```

Comment: What version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: it is the version 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because cakephp uses **convention over configuration** you should use `id` for your table primary id field. In your example you could find what you are looking for like this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $supplier = $this->Supplier->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Supplier.id_supp' => $id
        )
    ));
    $this->set(array(
        'supplier' => $supplier,
        '_serialize' => array('supplier')
    ));
}
```

or like this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Supplier->primaryKey = $id;
    $supplier = $this->Supplier->find('first');
    $this->set(array(
        'supplier' => $supplier,
        '_serialize' => array('supplier')
    ));
}
```

or like this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $supplier = $this->Supplier->findByIdSupp($id);
    $this->set(array(
        'supplier' => $supplier,
        '_serialize' => array('supplier')
    ));
}
```

Choose what ever pleases you the most.